# How to run python file from subfolder so current folder file path automatically detect and edit data?

Tags: python

Y.py python file location `"D:\\Folder\\Sub Folder\\Y.py"`
1.html file location `"D:\\Folder\\1.html"`

every time Folder name change python code outFileName has to edit.There is any way Folder path catch automatically.

python code is

```
import os
import glob
import re

html = ""
strPath = os.path.realpath(__file__)
print( f"Full Path    :{strPath}" )
nmFolders = strPath.split( os.path.sep )
print( f"Folder Name  :{nmFolders[-2]}" )
for X in {nmFolders[-2]}:

   for file in sorted(glob.glob( os.path.join('*.html') )):
        for Y in {'*.webp', '*.png', '*.jpg'}:
             for image in sorted(glob.glob( os.path.join(Y))[:1]):

                for X in {nmFolders[-2]}:
                   html += f'''<div class="card"><a href ="{os.path.realpath(file)}"><img class="card__image" src="{os.path.realpath(image)}" width="200px alt=""><div class="card__content"><p1>{X}</p1></div><div class="card__info"></div></div></a>'''
    

for X in {nmFolders[-2]}:
                                         outFileName = "D:\\Folder\\1.html"

# Read the contents of the HTML file into a string
with open(outFileName, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    existing_html = f.read()

if html not in existing_html:
    # Write the new HTML to the file
    with open(outFileName, "a", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(html + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

so what is changing? The parent folder that contains
`Y.py` and `1.html`?

what is the "Folder Path" you are trying to catch automatically? Sharing your code doesn't clarify what you are trying to do in this situation.

Assuming you are trying to catch `D:\\Folder`, you can traverse the current directory you're in using the `..` in your file path.

so if you current directory (aka current folder) is
`D:\\Folder\\Sub Folder\\Y.py`
you can get to
`D:\\Folder\\1.html`
by using
`..\\1.html`

so basically two dots: `..`, means "go up one folder from where I currently am"